# Notifications for Joomla extension updates

Tags: content-management-system, joomla

Is there an extension that would check whether there are newer versions available to the installed extensions on a Joomla site, and would notify the site administrator?

Ideally, I am looking for something similar to Drupal's "Update" module.

I understand that there is no central place for keeping all these modules and their versions for Joomla, but at least a lot of them are available on the [Joomla Extensions](http://extensions.joomla.org/) site, along with the needed information, so perhaps somebody wrote a tool that checks that source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha, looks like this is to be included in Joomla 1.6, according to [this description](http://docs.joomla.org/Help16:Extensions_Extension_Manager_Update) (check out the "Find Updates" button, looks great).

Answer (score 0):

But if you are using Joomla 1.5 until 1.6 is stable check out: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/installers/9332

Excellent for keeping components up to date :)

Comment: From the component description it looks like it updates Joomla core only (which is very easy to do anyway), and no mention about updating extensions. Am I missing something and it can update extensions as well?

Comment: Installed it, but it has nothing to do with extension updates. The dev says that he tries to find time to backport the logic from Joomla 1.6, so may be that'll happen before stable 1.6 is out (and we've all migrated :)), but for now this doesn't seem to offer much. Thanks for the answer, anyway.